# Conditional jump or move depends on uniinitalized values

Tags: c, hash, valgrind

I am getting the following error from valgrind. Conditional jump or move depends on uninitalized values. I have looked around at similar questions but I am not able to find out whats wrong. I have initialized all the variables, but still..

```
unsigned long hash_word(const char *str)
 {
  unsigned long hash = 5381;
  int c = 0;

  while((c = *str)) // The error occurs here
   {
    hash = ((hash<<5) + hash) + c;
    str++;
   }

 return hash%1999099;
}
```

The value of str is passed from the main function. I am using leak-check=full and track-origins=yes. Thanks in advance for the help.

First I am initializing a node.

```
    typedef struct node{
     char word[46];
     struct node *next;
  } node;
```

The calling code is

```
  while(!(feof(fp)))
 {
   node *n =  malloc(sizeof(node));
   if (n == NULL)
    {
     return false;
    }
   else
    {
     fscanf(fp,"%s",n->word);

     index = hash_word(n->word);
     .
     .
     .    // further code
   }
```

Comment: How do you obtain `str` ? Show us the caller code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a misunderstanding in what `feof()` does. It doesn't return a true value until *after* a read has failed due to EOF. Therefore, in your last iteration, the `fscanf()` call fails and thus does not initialize `n->word`. You should check the return value of `fscanf()`. If it hits EOF it returns the C value `EOF`. You could also check for the value `1` indicating a single field was successfully converted.

Comment: But if feof fails, then node *n will not be malloc'd. Then the if loop should catch it.

Comment: `feof()` doesn't return true until after the read has failed. But between the time the code makes the failing read and checks for EOF, it attempts to use the value that it (didn't) read.